# How to pass JSON to Sass in ReactJS?

Tags: css, json, reactjs, sass, webpack

I'm working on a React/Redux app with Webpack that displays UI components and allows the user to change colors of those components. I am styling using CSS Modules with scss. I would prefer to keep all the styling within the scss files rather than doing any inline styles with JS. I am looking for a way to pass properties from the React component into the corresponding scss file.

For example, I'm getting the button color from the React props. I need to find a way to turn that into a Sass variable and inject into the scss file. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best option is to use [**react-css-themr**](https://github.com/javivelasco/react-css-themr). With it you can assign class name based to selection of user, or, in your case, you can use the [context-theming](https://github.com/javivelasco/react-css-themr#context-theming) for choose right scss to apply on component.

This is used on [react-toolbox](http://react-toolbox.com/) project for theming the material components, if you want to watch a good example.